# How to calculate the power of 2 for the column of DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to calculate the power of 2 for the column `p` using Spark 2.2 and Scala:

But if I do it this way, I get the error, because `($"ki" / $"ni")` is the column, not Double.

```
df.withColumn("p",(lit(1) - scala.math.pow(($"ki" / $"ni").as[Double],2))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [inbuilt pow function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#pow(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("power_of_two", pow($"p", lit(2)))
```

Comment: Or just `$"p" * $"p"`.

Comment: yeah @user6910411, but using inbuilt functions should be more efficient. isn't that so?

Comment: This is as inbuilt as possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**POW function with sample data**

```
val someDF = Seq(
     (8,"A"),
     (12,"B"),
     (16,"C")).toDF("number","letter")

someDF.withColumn("pow_example",pow(2,$"number")).show()
```